# Don't preview first item in menu topnav

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav) (code copied below) the first item "Home" is always displayed. How can I hide the "Home" item like all the others when the window is small enough?

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean by “small enough” :-)

Comment: You have **a:not(:first-child)** which skips first child which is home :D

Comment: @LucianoGiordano "Small enough" meaning when the window is small enough to show the menu in the top navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the media query has specify a:not(:first-child) but other child dispay:none. in other to hide all the child elements including the firstchild change

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

to 

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          .topnav a {display: none;}
          .topnav a.icon {
            float: right;
            display: block;
          }
        }
```

Comment: You should say why

Comment: the reason if because of the media query has specify a:not(:first-child) but other child dispay:none;

Comment: I know why add in your answer for others